# How to fix CSS as it is not working in Iphone? offset-distance, offset-path

Tags: css, ios

The following code is not working in Iphone, but works fine in Web and Android Chorme. The bike is not moving and all bikes are shown in the same place.

````
.bikes
{
    offset-path: path("M-230,2 C-100,50 100,50 230,0");
    offset-distance: 50%;
    transform-origin: $bikeAnchor1;
    position: absolute;
    width: $bikeWidth;
    height: $bikeHeight;

    
    // Fila 1
    &#bike0
    {
        offset-distance: 55% - $bikeSeparacion1 * 3.4;
        transform-origin: $bkeAnchor1;
    }

    &#bike1
    {
        offset-distance: 50% - $bikeSeparacion1 * 2.3;
        transform-origin: $bikeAnchor1;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my animated SVG.

The problem coming from the "offset-distance". The IOS does not support this parameter.
[Check here](https://caniuse.com/?search=offset-distance)